# Ошибка установки соединения с кластером серверов

Tags: 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста, не сталкивались ли вы с такой проблемой -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю ./rac cluster list и получаю такое сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что RAS на хосте был запущен от другой версии клиента, нашел процесс - убил его, и запустил командой:

```
./ras --daemon cluster
```

После все заработало как надо, и тоже выполнился корректно.

```
./rac cluster list
```